# How to pass powershell script variable values to downstream task in Release pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Created a CD with few steps starting from "Azure PowerShell Task".

In Azure PowerShell tasks, executing a PowerShell script file and set a value in a variable.
At the end of the script I have set the variable with a value –

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable;isSecret=false;isOutput=true;]myvalue"
```

**myvariable** is the variable

**myvalue** is the value.

Based on the value of “myvariable”; downstream task will be executed or skipped. Mentioned "Custom Condition" in downstream task (Task - Azure Create or Update Resource) –

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables[‘myvariable’], ‘myvalue’))
```

But, it’s always skipping the step; despite the correct value is passing. Here is my release tasks snippet -
[image]

How do I overcome?

Comment: Can you verify one step after the Azure PowerShell task that the myvariable get the myvalue? (add another task and print the myvariable value)

Comment: Created one powershell task and printing the value of $(myvariable). Showing error -  The term 'myvariable' is not recognized. Tried to print Write-Host $myvariable, no values is printing.

Comment: can you try replacing the `echo` with `Write-Host`?

Comment: Tried earlier, but not getting the value

Comment: i think with powershell you should use `$env:myvariable`. also try your condition like so: `$(myvariable), myvalue`. also, worth nothing, you are probably trying to do something you are not supposed to do with this approach

Comment: @DebasisGhosh can you try this code  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable]myvalue" instead of echo

Comment: $env:myvariable tried earlier but no luck. just wanted to restrict few steps which we don't want to execute every time once the CD is triggered. Thanks

Comment: @Jayendran - Yes, I tried but not getting any value

Comment: can you share images of your tasks?

Comment: Shared the tasks image, Thanks.

Comment: Share the First 2 tasks also...

Comment: in first task i have written PowerShell script and remove other stuff. Now the script is - echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable;isSecret=false;isOutput=true;]N1"

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable;isSecret=false;isOutput=true;]myvalue"
```

And then

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['myvariable'], 'myvalue'))
```

In the second part, the code you pasted in has the incorrect quote types, you had curly quotes ‘ ’ rather than the normal straight quotes ' '

You often end up with the wrong quotes if copying / pasting from Word or Outlook. I'm sure there's a proper a typography term for them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your valuable input. Resolution -
*PowerShell Script* -

```
$myvalue="hello"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable]$myvalue"
```

Assign value ("hello") in a variable ($myvalue), then set it in "Write-Host". Direct value did not work for me.
Now we can use/verify "myvariable" value in downstream tasks in Custom Condition as mentioned by @Alex KeySmith.

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['myvariable'], 'hello'))
```

task -

[image]

Works in Build and Release pipeline.