# Set variable in bash script and access in expression in Azure Pipelines

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using an `azure-pipelines.yml` script to source control my build pipeline.

In a task I have defined a bash script to set some variables for certificates paths depending on whether we are building for production or anything else:

```
 steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "Building for $BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"
      if [ "$BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME" = "production" ]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=configuration]Release"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=certificatesPath]${{ parameters.productionCertificatesPath }}"
      else
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=configuration]Staging"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=certificatesPath]${{ parameters.stagingCertificatesPath }}"
      fi
    name: environmentVars
```

How can I then access these variables in an expression in a later build step in the same job? I know I can access them like `$(environmentVars.configuration)` and `$(environmentVars.certificatesPath)`, but this syntax doesn't work for expressions. Here is where I'm trying to access the variables:

```
signingProvisioningProfileFile: ${{ format('{0}/app.mobileprovision', <ACCESS VARIABLE HERE>) }}
```

Comment: What is `signingProvisioningProfileFile`? Is that a build step parameter, or part of a Bash script?

Comment: its an input to a task @DanielMann

Comment: `$(configuration)` and `$(certificatesPath)`. If it's in another stage in the yaml file you'll need to use `isOutput=true` on your `task.setvariable`

Comment: Possibel duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53154702/736079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this was to just bake the constants I wanted into the initial setting of the variable instead of trying to format it later. For example:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=certificatesPath]${{ parameters.productionCertificatesPath }}/app.mobileprovision"
```